# Scala: read and save all elements of an Iterable

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have an Iterable[T] that is really a stream of unknown length, and want to read it all and save it into something that is still an instance of Iterable. I really do have to read it and save it; I can't do it in a lazy way. The original Iterable can have a few thousand elements, at least. What's the most efficient/best/canonical way? Should I use an ArrayBuffer, a List, a Vector?

Suppose xs is my Iterable. I can think of doing these possibilities:

```
xs.toArray.toIterable     // Ugh?
xs.toList                 // Fast?
xs.copyToBuffer(anArrayBuffer)
Vector(xs: _*)            // There's no toVector, sadly. Is this construct as efficient?
```

EDIT: I see by the questions I should be more specific. Here's a strawman example:

```
def f(xs: Iterable[SomeType]) {    // xs might a stream, though I can't be sure
    val allOfXS = <xs all read in at once>
    g(allOfXS)
    h(allOfXS)    // Both g() and h() take an Iterable[SomeType]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean saying _still an instance of Iterable_?

Comment: I mean convertedThing.instanceOf[Iterable[T]] is true. I have to pass it on to something that is expecting an Iterable. I should have left out "still"; that just has to do with the context of the code.

Comment: There's no `toVector`, but there's `toIndexedSeq`.

Comment: Is there a guarantee that your `xs` is non-infinite? If so then I see no reason why `toList` or `toIndexedSeq` wouldn't work.

Comment: @J-P.P.: toIndexedSeq seems like the best choice for my situation. If you make it an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Why do you need to read all of it anyway? Just to make sure, you do realize `Iterable` is reusable, right? It is `Iterator` which is not reusable.

Comment: Are you aware, that `Stream` does not re-evaluate its elements on each time, but only the first time? So going through the `Stream` a second time will not trigger the computations to produce the elements a second time.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. When I said "Stream", I meant a Java InputStream. We have an Iterable that reads from one. I was not even aware of Scala Streams and their reusability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy.  A few thousand elements is nothing, so it hardly matters unless it's a really tight loop.  So the flippant answer is: use whatever you feel is most elegant.

But, okay, let's suppose that this is actually in some tight loop, and you can predict or have benchmarked your code enough to know that this is performance-limiting.

Your best performance for an immutable solution will likely be a `Vector`, used like so:

```
Vector() ++ xs
```

In my hands, this can copy a 10k iterable about 4k-5k times per second.  `List` is about half the speed.

If you're willing to try a mutable solution under the hood, `xs.toArray.toIterable` usually takes the cake with about 10k copies per second.  `ArrayBuffer` is about the same speed as `List`.

If you actually know the size of the target (i.e. `size` is `O(1)` or you know it from somewhere else), you can shave off another 20-30% of the execution speed by allocating just the right size and writing a while loop.

If it's actually primitives, you can gain a factor of 10 by writing your own specialized `Iterable`-like-thing that acts on arrays and converts to regular collections via the underlying array.

Bottom line: for a great blend of power, speed, and flexibility, use `Vector() ++ xs` in most situations.  `xs.toIndexedSeq` defaults to the same thing, with the benefit that if it's already a `Vector` that it will take no time at all (and chains nicely without using parens), and the drawback that you are relying upon a convention, not a specification for behavior (and it takes 1-3 more characters to type).

Answer (score 1):

How about `Stream.force`?

> Forces evaluation of the whole stream and returns it.

Comment: It's passed in as an Iterable and is not necessarily always a Stream, so I can't know that force will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard. An `Iterable`'s methods are defined in terms of its `iterator`, but that gets overridden by subtraits. For instance, `IndexedSeq` methods are usually defined in terms of `apply`.

There is the question of why do you want to *copy* the `Iterable`, but I suppose you might be guarding against the possibility of it being mutable. If you do not want to copy it, then you need to rephrase your question.

If you are going to copy it, and you want to be sure all elements are copied in a strict manner, you could use `.toList`. That will not copy a `List`, but a `List` does not need to be copied. For anything else, it will produce a new copy.

Comment: A new copy is fine. It is an incoming stream of data, which I must pass on for reuse several times, in succession, and not in parallel. The example after the "EDIT" above indicates the spirit of the code: g() and h() process the data, and they must run sequentially. In reality, f() actually just returns the Iterable to its caller, who reuses the data several times. I don't have the ability to change the calling structure, so it's a somewhat odd problem.